# SQL Select retornar apenas um de varios

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

tenho duas tabelas.

Tabela "usuario" que tem 5 linhas e 5 usuarios.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e a tabela "locacao" que tem 20 registros, utilizando 5 foreign key de ID da tabela usuario

[image]

Quando eu utilizo esse select que fiz

```
select u.nome from usuario u join locacao l on l.UsuarioId = u.id
```

ele me retorna os seguintes valores...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha duvida é, como faço para ele retornar apenas um valor de cada?

retornar assim.

---

- Pablo
- Wagner
- Neto
- Lucas
- Alan

---

sem repetir varias vezes o mesmo nome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para retornar apenas um valor de cada, sem repetição, deves utilizar DISTINCT, a query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.nome FROM usuario u JOIN locacao l ON l.UsuarioId = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Boas vindas ao stackoverflow!

Para resolver seu problema vamos utilizar a cláusula **DISTINCT** que 
é usado para retornar apenas valores **DISTINTOS**, ou seja, sem repetições.

no seu caso basta apenas adicionar o termo DISTINCT após o SELECT, ficando:

SELECT DISTINCT ... [*resto do escopo de sua query*]

Espero ter ajudado!